# Cannot Debug WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Brand new laptop.  It is running Windows seven media center.  IIS is installed.  Anyway, I just downloaded the WCFRestService with key template and when I try to debug I get:

The operation could not be completed.  Unspecified Error.

When I try to browse I get:

Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio Development Web Server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try running Visual Studio as an admin?